# A question on collection and replacement in Sigma(n)-KP

Tags: set-theory

Does Sigma(n)-KP, i.e. Kripke-Platek set theory with Sigma(n)-collection and Sigma(n)-separation have Sigma(n)-replacement.

Comment: It helps if you also give some references and context to your question, I am not an expert but would be happy to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If we have a set $A$ and for every $a\in A$ there is a unique $b$ such that $\varphi(a,b,z)$, where $\varphi$ has complexity $\Sigma_n$, then by $\Sigma_n$ collecton there is a set $B$ such that every $a\in A$ has a $b\in B$ with $\varphi(a,b,z)$. But perhaps there is extra stuff in $B$, so this set may be too large to verify the desired instance of $\Sigma_n$-replacement. But we may apply $\Sigma_n$-separation to form the set $\{b\in B\mid \exists a\in A\ \varphi(a,b,z)\}$, which does fulfill the desired instance of $\Sigma_n$-replacement.

Comment: Thanks. That was easy and I should have seen it. Sometimes there are curtains before the windows. :)

Comment: Interestingly, to me, then Sigma(n)-KP is stronger than Sigma(n)-ZF minus power set as power set is needed to get Sigma(n)-collection from Sigma(n)-replacement.